# Showing that a group is lattice-ordered

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

Say I have a set $S$ with a group operation $\cdot$ and lattice ordering $\leq$. Suppose further that:

1. $x\leq 1\implies xy\leq y$
2. $x\geq 1\implies xy\geq y$

For all $x,y$.

Does it follow that $(S,\cdot,\leq)$ is a lattice ordered group? i.e. does it hold that $(x\vee y)z=xz\vee yz$ and $(x\wedge y)z=xz\wedge yz$ for all $x,y,z$?

I think this is true because I can't think of any counter examples, but I'm having trouble proving it. Any hints?

EDIT: This was also asked on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142044/conditions-for-a-group-to-be-lattice-ordered)

Comment: Do you really mean 'a group with a lattice ordering' at the beginning? What is the dual of $x\leq 1\implies xy\leq y$?

Comment: @GitGud: Sorry, this probably wasn't idiomatic. Can you see my edit?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Don't you mean "a group with a partial order $\leq$"? If you don't, what is a lattice ordering?

Comment: @GitGud: A partial order that is also a lattice: every two elements have both a meet and a join.

Comment: I don't see any duality as $x^{-1}≤1 ⇒ (x^{-1})(xy) ≤ (xy) ⇒ y ≤ xy$ and $x^{-1}≤1 ⇒ (x^{-1})(x) ≤ (x) ⇒ 1 ≤ x$

Comment: @Keinstein: I agree $x\leq 1\Leftrightarrow x^{-1}\geq 1$ but I'm not sure what you're implying - are you saying that my (1) and (2) imply each other?

Comment: @Xodarap: yes. from $x≤1$ follows $1≤x^{-1}$ from 2. we get $xy≤x^{-1}(xy)$, as $x^{-1}(xy) = y$ the last statement reads as $xy≤y$. Thus we have used 2. to prove 1.

Comment: @Keinstein: i actually dont think this is true. You have to assume $x^{-1}\geq 1$ in order to use (2), and that's what you wanted to prove in the first place. Right?

Comment: You are right: I missed the case $x^{-1}\|1$. Nevertheless: both implications are implied by right-ordered groups ($x≤y ⇒ xz≤yz$). I stopped at this point. Do you have any information about the set $\{ x\mid 1≤x\}$ or about the implication above?

Comment: Could you link the mathoverflow questions here?

Comment: BTW: “Didn't get any anwser.“ Is not fair. You get at least a hint to right-ordered groups.

Comment: This was answered [on Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142044/conditions-for-a-group-to-be-lattice-ordered).

Comment: Added a link. And I don't mean any insult by saying I didn't get an answer, I'm just saying that the problem remained unsolved.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a partially ordered group then it is also a lattice ordered group. The usual way is to prove 
$$a≤b⇒xay≤xby.$$

**Edit:** Your task is to prove that it is a partially ordered group. 
Your implications are a consequence from the definition of right-ordered groups $$x≤y ⇒ xz≤yz$$.

You have either more information about your structure or you are stuck with a right-ordered group. So your question reads: Is every right-lattice-ordered group already a $\ell$-group?

So looking at [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2621) survey we know that such a group can be embedded into an $\ell$-group. As it doesn't tell anything about isomorphy neither as fact nor as open question nor as recently answered question, I guess the anwer to your question is: No.

Maybe someone who is familiar with right-ordered groups can help you.

Comment: 1. Not all po-groups are l-groups. Consider the trivially ordered group $\forall x: x\leq x$ - what would the supremum of $x$ and $y$ be? 2. I agree this is what I need to prove, but I don't see how to prove it when $a,b,x,y\parallel 1$

Comment: 1. That is true, but you already mentioned that it's a lattice. 2. me neither ;-) But if it's not a homework then you might know some more properties that could help. Maybe you should have a look on right-ordered groups (I'm not really familiar with them).